# ¿Cómo realizar triggers con datos base de datos?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, trigger, sql

Buen día amigos, tengo la siguiente tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi duda es si puedo ejecutar un trigger a la hora final de cada registro y hacer un insert o cualquier otra operación en la base de datos, muchas gracias

Comment: No sé si entiendo exactamente lo que necesitas, pero por lo que te he entendido, puedes utilizar el trigger de on update e incluir la lógica de si la columna hora_final tiene valor para realizar las acciones que necesites

Answer (score 1):

Como bien sabes, los `triggers` se ejecutar bajo `3` condiciones:

```
 - Actualizar
 - Eliminar
 - Insertar.
```

Puntualmente, para tu respuesta si, puedes insertar un dato en otra tabla (o en la misma), cuando algo en ese campo `"hora_final"` como ejemplo te paso el siguiente código dónde se muestra una actualización del campo fecha cuando se inserta un dato en la tabla `tblpoll`:

```
CREATE trigger [dbo].[tblPollDate]
on [dbo].[tblPoll]
for Insert
as
declare @id int
SELECT  @id=id

from inserted
   BEGIN
        UPDATE tblPoll
        SET fecha = getdate() WHERE ID= @id
    END
```

Cambia el `update` por `insert` en la tabla que necesites del ejemplo anterior.